# ExtJS display link in new tab

Tags: javascript, extjs, hyperlink

I am using ExtJS version 2. I am clicking a button to add new tab to a TabPanel. The new tab function looks like this:

```
function addTab(tabTitle, targetUrl){
        tabPanel.add({
        title: tabTitle,
        iconCls: 'tabs',
        closable:true
    }).show();
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to get the targetUrl and display it in new tab. If i set `html: targetUrl`, my tab content would obviously be just a text with my URL. If I set up the `autoLoad: {url: targetUrl}` it works but it is reading the file contents as if they were texts or scripts.. The problem is that I would need to open images and I just get their source with `autoLoad`, not the actual display of the image. I just want my new tab to act like a new pop-up window with a default link.

Can anybody help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I have used the ManagedIframe script witch happens to do exactly what I requested. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah that script basically does what I recommended. I just wasn't sure if that's what you were looking for or not.

Answer (score 2):

In Extjs you can load any panel with the contents of a url. You can do it like this

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Your Tile',
    closable: true,
    iconCls: 'tabs',
    autoLoad: {
        url: targetUrl
    }
});
tabPanel.add(panel);
tabPanel.doLayout();
tabPanel.setActiveTab(panel);
```

You can find more details in the Extjs API documentation.

Comment: Please, execute the code you posted and tell me if you can display an image with its path as targetUrl. Because I can't. I get characters like this: "�����I�+�ǈ���%��xjE9" because you can't just send an image through GET or POST..

Comment: Right. The URL must return an image tag. If it returns an image, you need to have an onLoad handler which updates the content to be "<img src=\""+url+"\">"

Answer (score 0):

if the URL is an HTML snippit, not a full page, you'll need to make an AJAX call to fetch the contents and update the tab. If the page is a full page, including `<html>` and `<body>` tags, then you should make the tab contain an iFrame with `"src=\""+url+"\""`

Comment: I thought of an iframe but how can I set its width and height based on my center panel size ?

Comment: Try width="100%" height="100%" -- if that doesn't work add an onresize handler to the panel which resizes the iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to sent the image through the response, you can simply specify the url of the image as the html of the panel.

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Your Tile',
    closable: true,
    iconCls: 'tabs',
    url:'<img src="http://yourdomain.com/images/image.gif" />'
});
```

Comment: Because it's not only images that I have to send. I have to send PDF files, html files, any kind.